# Kubernetes Deployments across the Datacenters

Tags: docker, kubernetes, ceph, kubernetes-health-check, kubernetes-mesos

Is it possible to failover the traffic from a mysql k8s deployment running in one datacenter to a deployment running in another datacenter along with its storage?

If yes , Do we need to spread the same k8s cluster on multiple datacenters or we have to run separate k8s clusters in each datacenter?

How k8s will ship or manage the storage volume across the datacenters? Do we need a special type of cloud storage for that purpose?

note:   I just qouted mysql as an example of application that needs to store some data , it can be anything stateful that needs to carry over its data volumes. it is not that kind of HA like mysql-HA , it is just starting serving the application as it is from somewhere else automatically along with its data. any application that stores data to volume.

How can we achieve HA for our stateful application across the datacenters using k8s.

Thanks

Comment: See the docs for details on what is currently possible as well as limitations: https://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/multiple-zones/

Comment: so there is not a clear yes or no answer to this problem? yet

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use Kubernetes to achieve HA.

I would recommend using MySQL Replication(i.e. Master/Slave configuration) to achieve HA. More info in the [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication.html) on how to set replication up.

In one data center, you would have a Master, and in your other data center, you would have the slave. You can even have multiple slaves in multiple data centers.

If problems arise on the master, you can automatically failover to a slave using the [mysqlfailover utility](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-utilities/1.5/en/mysqlfailover.html). This way you have your data in 2 data centers that is in sync.

I'm not sure if this exactly fits your use cases, but it is one option for enabling HA on your MySQL database.

Comment: I just qouted mysql as an example of application that needs to store some data , it can be anything stateful that needs to carry over its data volumes. it is not that kind of HA like mysql-HA , it is just starting serving the application as it is from somewhere else automatically. any application that stores data to volume.